# Git требует пароль при каждом push

Tags: git, github

Все работало верно, но после несколько хаотичных экспериментов `git` стал просить логин пароль при каждом `push` и в `IDE` и в терминале. Помогите пожалуйста это исправить назад. Но `ssh` ключи я кажется не трогал.

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/triodjangopiter/account-manager
  Push  URL: https://github.com/triodjangopiter/account-manager
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    feature/custom_filter tracked
    feature/toolbar       tracked
    master                tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    feature/custom_filter merges with remote feature/custom_filter
    feature/toolbar       merges with remote feature/toolbar
    master                merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    feature/custom_filter pushes to feature/custom_filter (up to date)
    feature/toolbar       pushes to feature/toolbar       (up to date)
    master                pushes to master                (up to date)
```

Comment: У вас origin это https ссылка. Нужно ее заменить на ssh: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:triodjangopiter/account-manager.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это довольно частая ошибка. `origin` нужно заменить на `ssh` ссылку:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:triodjangopiter/account-manager.git
```